# How can I replace every comma with a space in a text file before a pattern using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with lines in this format:

```
FirstName,LastName,SSN,$x.xx,$x.xx,$x.xx
FirstName,MiddleInitial,LastName,SSN,$x.xx,$x.xx,$x.xx
```

The lines could be in either format. For example:

```
Joe,Smith,123-45-6789,$150.00,$150.00,$0.00
Jane,F,Doe,987-65-4321,$250.00,$500.00,$0.00
```

I want to basically turn everything before the SSN into a single field for the name thus:

```
Joe Smith,123-45-6789,$150.00,$150.00,$0.00
Jane F Doe,987-65-4321,$250.00,$500.00,$0.00
```

How can I do this using PowerShell? I think I need to use ForEach-Object and at some point replace "," with " ", but I don't know how to specify the pattern. I also don't know how to use a ForEach-Object with a $_.Where so that I can specify the "SkipUntil" mode.

Thanks very much!

Comment: `-replace '(?<=\w),',' '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathias is correct; you want to use the `-replace` operator, which uses regular expressions. I think this will do what you want:

```
$string -replace ',(?=.*,\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})',' '
```

The regular expression uses a lookahead (?=) to look for any commas that are followed by any number of any character (. is any character, * is any number of them including 0) that are then followed by a comma immediately followed by a SSN (\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}). The concept of "zero-width assertions", such as this lookahead, simply means that it is used to determine the match, but it not actually returned as part of the match.

That's how we're able to match only the commas in the names themselves, and then replace them with a space.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks very much. RegEx always gives me heartburn.

Comment: This answer could go from good to great if you explain how that regular expression works (what a look-ahead is, why it's important that it's zero-width, etc.).  ;)

Comment: So you're using a positive look-ahead (which I didn't know existed) to look for any commas between the start of the first comma in the string and the comma before the ,SSN expression? I think I understand it except for the period before the * in ?=.*...it that specifying that it's zero width?

Comment: Almost; I'm updating the answer to provide some more details, but you've basically got it.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's answered, and neatly so, but I tried to come up with an alternative to using a regex - count the number of commas in a line, then replace either the first one, or the first two, commas in the line.

But strings can't count how many times a character appears in them without using the regex engine(*), and replacements can't be done a specific number of times without using the regex engine(**), so it's not very neat:

```
$comma = [regex]","
Get-Content data.csv | ForEach { 

    $numOfCommasToReplace = $comma.Matches($_).Count - 4
    $comma.Replace($_, ' ', $numOfCommasToReplace)

} | Out-File data2.csv
```

Avoiding the regex engine entirely, just for fun, gets me things like this:

```
Get-Content .\data.csv | ForEach { 

    $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7 = $_ -split ','
    if ($7) {"$1 $2 $3,$4,$5,$6,$7"} else {"$1 $2,$3,$4,$5,$6"}

} | Out-File data2.csv
```

---

(*) `($line -as [char[]] -eq ',').Count`

(**) `while ( #counting ) { # split/mangle/join }`